# i am new jquery and java script Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined and $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

before asking here i have tried many types and times but no use i am getting same error both Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined and $ is not defined.
my code is

```
<script src="js/jQuery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jQuery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/floating-1.12.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/stickyfloat.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)  
    {  
        $('#floatdiv').addFloating(  
            {  
                targetRight: 10,  
                targetBottom: 10,  
                snap: true  
            });  
    });  
</script> 
<script>
$(".bt").click(function() {
    $('.easing').parent().hide();
});
</script>
```

please help me

Comment: You must have found many related questions while posting this one.. Go through them..

Comment: Are you certain you are not also getting a 404 error when trying to load js/jQuery.min.js?

Answer (score 0):

$ - is the defult character for jquery.
you had ovveride it when you wrote it as function parameter,Just try remove the param $ from function:

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function()

    {

        $('#floatdiv').addFloating(

            {

                targetRight: 10,

                targetBottom: 10,

                snap: true

            });

    });
```

Comment: what is the problem at my answer? why did you vote down?